# Props lost after navigate and cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In an app I'm currently working on, the authentification has been done like this, to pass user's data into children components (in App.js, I would have rather used `useContext` to access user data in whatever component) `[App.js]`:

```
const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {

    // fetch user data from database, ...

    return <>{React.cloneElement(children, { user: {...user, ...userExtraData} })}</>;
```

};

Then, an example of a `Route` is specified as `[App.js]`:

```
 <Route
      path="/addgame"
      element={
              <RequireAuth>
                  <FormAddGame />
              </RequireAuth>

            }
           
  />
```

However, my current problem is the following:

From a `ComponentA`, I want to navigate to `/addgame` (=`FormAddGame` component, see below) while setting an `existingGame` prop. Thus, I use `[ComponentA.js]`:

```
let navigate = useNavigate()    
navigate('addgame', { existingGame: game })
```

The said `FormAddGame` component is `[FormAddGame.js]`:

```
function FormAddGame({ user }) {

    const { existingGame } = useLocation()

    console.log(existingGame)
    ...
}
export default FormAddGame;
```

However, while I correctly navigate to `/addgame`, the `existingGame` prop stays `undefined` once in `FormAddGame` while it should be not (as `game` is not `undefined`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing props like this:

```
navigate("addgame", { state: { existingGame: game } });
```

and destructure like this:

```
const { state: { existingGame } = {} } = useLocation();
```

Comment: Yes. I have realized yesterday, after reading the doc again, that I was missing the ´state ´.